# My PHP function cant reach a json in my REST API, I can't find the regular expression to do this in .htaccess

Tags: api, rest, file, .htaccess

I want to reach a file in
`website.com/api/src/data.json`

I cannot get the .json file and I feel this has to do with rule (3) not working properly or totally being ignored because of rule (2) because the response I am getting a message from `website.com/api/index.php`

my .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

#(1)DEFAULT HTTPS UPGRADER
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests;"
</IfModule>

# HERE GOES THE BAD REWRITE RULE
#(2) redirect all api calls to /api/index.php
RewriteRule ^api/((?!index\.php$).+)$ api/index.php [L,NC]

#(3) If the request is a file, folder or symlink that exists, serve it up
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

#(4) otherwise, serve your index.html app
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.html [L]
```

How can I fix this?

EDIT: I somewhat kind of fixed this by putting rule (2) below rule (3) but now some folders are not considered as endpoints

Comment: `^api/((?!index\.php$).+)$` matches on all request paths starting with `api/`, and then _not_ immediately followed by `index.php`. So it matches for `api/src/data.json` as well, and rewrites that to `api/index.php`.

Comment: "fixed this by putting rule (2) below rule (3) but now **some** folders are not considered as endpoints" - Yes, your rules were in the wrong order. So, what do you want to happen exactly? It's unusual that "physical directories" are endpoints for an API. And the original rule #3 excludes all directories (and makes them accessible). Maybe you should just remove that _condition_? But you mention only "some" folders?

Comment: I'm sorry, English isn't my first language. What I meant is that `website.com/src` throws a forbidden error but not managed by index.php as a failed endpoint, I don't know if this could lead to future errors in my API.

By placing rule (2) below (3) everything is ok except for symlinks, I can't find how to make them work properly

Comment: Last problem was solved, I found out what I was doing wrong with my php class, I wasn't placing /src on symlink so files in that folder weren't going to solve from index.php in the /api folder